# Visual Studio 15 vs 2015 + Update 2

Tags: visual-studio

I can choose from two possibilities of new Visual Studio installation

- Visual Studio 15 Preview
- Visual Studio 2015 + Update 2

But I'm a little bit confused what do these versions mean.

- What are the main differences?
- What version is better to choose?
- Can I expect that all the features in VS 15 are available in VS 2015 + Update 2?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 is a stable version of Visual Studio 2015. Visual Studio 15 Preview is the new stuff and it's not stable.

Comment: No, all features on "15" aren't on 2015, especially after a while. They wouldn't need a new version if they were, we'd just have 2015.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Visual Studio 15 is the version *after* Visual Studio 2015. The "15" is effectively the mostly-internal version number, and the "2015" is the branding version. Yes, it's very confusing.

Other internal/branding mappings:

- Visual Studio 97 / "Boston"
- Visual Studio 6.0 / "Aspen"
- Visual Studio 7 / "Rainier" => Visual Studio .NET 2002
- Visual Studio 7.1 / "Everett" => Visual Studio .NET 2003
- Visual Studio 8 / "Whidbey" => Visual Studio 2005
- Visual Studio 9 / "Orcas" => Visual Studio 2008
- Visual Studio 10 / "Rosario" => Visual Studio 2010
- Visual Studio 11 => Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Studio 12 => Visual Studio 2013
- Visual Studio 14 => Visual Studio 2015

Unless you want to experiment with prerelease software (which can be fun, don't get me wrong) you want to install Visual Studio 2015... and update 2 is the most recent release of that.

We don't yet know what the *branded* name of Visual Studio 15 will be - mostly because we don't know when it's going to be released.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to try new stuff, definitely. But do all the features and extensions work the same way in VS 15 as in previous versions 2013, 2015 etc.? I'll probably install both and I'll try it.

Comment: @JozefCechovsky: I wouldn't like to claim anything about it *all* working the same way - and I wouldn't be surprised if some extensions don't register themselves with VS15 yet. It's very, very new.

Comment: You might be a little wrong here. See e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008). VS 7 = 2002, 7.1 = 2003, 8 = 2005, 9 = 2008, 10 = 2010, 11 = 2012, 12 = 2013, 13 is skipped because of number 13, 14 = 2015

Comment: @a553: Thanks - not sure how I went wrong there, given that I consulted Wikipedia at least once :( Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever get confused about what internal number your version of Visual Studio is, look at the path that your Visual Studio shortcut targets. For example, Visual Studio 2015 targets "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **14.0**\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".